# Modules-Extra missing when upgrading kernel

Tags: wireless, upgrade, kernel

I have noticed that I regularly need to install linux-modules-extra on my laptop in order for my wifi to work (Dell XPS 9300). Running a sudo apt install will usually fix the issue (under bluetooth data tether), so I assume kernel updates are what's causing my setup to fail on occasion.

I'd like to know if there's any way to automatically run install the correct linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-XX-generic packages whenever there's a Kernel update.

Comment: I suspect that you are missing the linux-generic meta-package, which will ensure that upgrades work
correctly, and that supporting packages are also installed. Check: `sudo dpkg -s linux-generic | grep Status` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.